# Bootstrap select options not working in version 4.1.0

Tags: bootstrap-4, html-select

As I wanted dropdown with icons loaded whenever on clicking the select options

**Requirement:** The same piece of code needs to be implemented with BootStrap version 4.1.0. As of now whenever clicking on select dropdown doesn't appear.

**Actual Output:** The below code runs perfectly with BootStrap version 3.3.4

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Initiate with custom caret icon
    $('select.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    caretIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down'
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 2em;
}

pre {
    margin: 1em 0;
}

select.selectpicker {
    display: none;
    /* Prevent FOUC */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://thdoan.github.io/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://thdoan.github.io/bootstrap-select/css/bootstrap-select.css">

<h2>Select with Icons</h2>
<select title="Select your spell" class="selectpicker">
    <option>Select...</option>
    <option data-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" data-subtext="petrification">Eye of Medusa</option>
    <option data-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-fire" data-subtext="area damage">Rain of Fire</option>
</select>
```

**Expected Output**: The same piece of code needs to be implemented with BootStrap version 4.1.0

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Initiate with custom caret icon
    $('select.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    caretIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down'
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 2em;
}

pre {
    margin: 1em 0;
}

select.selectpicker {
    display: none;
    /* Prevent FOUC */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://thdoan.github.io/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://thdoan.github.io/bootstrap-select/css/bootstrap-select.css">

<h2>Select with Icons</h2>
<select title="Select your spell" class="selectpicker">
    <option>Select...</option>
    <option data-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" data-subtext="petrification">Eye of Medusa</option>
    <option data-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-fire" data-subtext="area damage">Rain of Fire</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You did not add right version of `bootstrap.js`
2. You did not add `popper.js`
3. You did not add right version of `bootstrap-select.js`

And since Bootstrap 4 does not support Glyphicon, you need to find some other way.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Initiate with custom caret icon
    $('select.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    caretIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down'
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 2em;
}

pre {
    margin: 1em 0;
}

select.selectpicker {
    display: none;
    /* Prevent FOUC */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">



<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.7/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.7/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>




<h2>Select with Icons</h2>
<select title="Select your spell" class="selectpicker">
    <option>Select...</option>
    <option data-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" data-subtext="petrification">Eye of Medusa</option>
    <option data-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-fire" data-subtext="area damage">Rain of Fire</option>
</select>
```